# Comparison of 2 samples from different uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given that $0\le a\le b<1$ and $p$ is uniform on $[a,1]$ and $q$ is uniform on $[b,1]$ then if $p$ and $q$ are random selections then what is the probability that $q>p$?

Edit: I am trying to work on an opening strategy for poker as a function of the ante, bet, number of players, and position at the table by doing a simulation. The a and b values represent the minimum opening/calling requirements assuming that the hand each player gets is from a uniform distribution on [0,1] with 1 being the best hand.

Comment: both answers give the same result! - thanks to André Nicolas and Did.

Answer (score 1):

**Procedure:** (We use $X$ instead of $p$, and $Y$ instead of $q$.)

So we want the probability that $Y\gt X$.

Note that the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is uniform on a certain rectangle. The area of that rectangle is $(1-a)(1-b)$. The joint density function is the reciprocal of this area, on the rectangle, and $0$ elsewhere.

Draw the coordinate axes, and draw a picture of the rectangle. Now draw the line $y=x$. We want the probability that we are *above* the line.

Find the area of the region which is in the rectangle but above the line. This could be done by integration, but calculus is unnecessary: basic geometry is enough.

Then divide this area by $(1-a)(1-b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb P(p\lt x)=(x-a)/(1-a)$ for every $x$ in $(b,1)$ and since $p$ and $q$ are independent,
$$
\mathbb P(p\lt q)=\int_b^1\mathbb P(p\lt x)\frac{\mathrm dx}{1-b}=\frac1{(1-a)(1-b)}\left[\frac{x^2}2\right]_{b-a}^{1-a}=\frac{1+b-2a}{2(1-a)}.
$$
Sanity checks: If $a=b$, the result is $\frac12$ (why?). If $b=1$, the result is $1$ (why?). The result is increasing with respect to $b$ (why?) and decreasing with respect to $a$ (why?).